# If $f\left(X_n, y\right) \overset{p}\to C$ and $Y_n\overset{p}\to y$, then $f\left(X_n,Y_n\right) \overset{p}\to C$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a continuous function. Suppose $f\left(X_n, y\right) \overset{p}\to C$ and $Y_n\overset{p}\to y$. Is it true that $f\left(X_n,Y_n\right) \overset{p}\to C$? Here, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are sequences of random variables. $y$ and $C$ are constants.

I think I can come up with a proof by considering something like

\begin{align}
|f(X_n,Y_n) - C| &= |f(X_n, Y_n) + f(X_n,y) - f(X_n,y) -C| \\
&\le |f(X_n, Y_n) - f(X_n,y)| + |f(X_n,y) - C|
\end{align}

and then use continuity of $f$. But I'm wondering if there's shorter proof? Slutsky doesn't seem to apply here. Continuous mapping theorem can only tell me that $f(x,Y_n) \overset{p}\to f(x,y)$ for every $x$.

**Update:** I wonder if there is more concise proof because I am also interested in general situation where $f(X_1,\cdots,X_n, y)\overset{p}\to C$ and $Y_n\overset{p}\to y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\left(x,y\right)=xy$, let $Y_n=y_n$, where $y_n\to 0$. Then 
$f\left(X_n,0\right)=0$, $Y_n\to 0$ almost surely but $f\left(X_n,Y_n\right)=X_ny_n$ hence the assumptions are satisfied whatever $X_n$ is so that we can easily construct a counter-example.

However, the claim is true if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R^2$.